# Easy WP SMTP - Getting an error

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, cpanel

So I have an issue. Everything was working fine on my website except when I had to perform an restore(lost some mail accounts in cPanel).

Now when I started from scratch, I used same Contact Form as before(plugin for WP) and when I set everything right for STMP Server(Easy WP STMP), to redirect my submission from the website to my gmail adress, I get an error.
The error is this: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

It appears that the only file with php I have is class-phpmailer.php (which is pretty long and I assume has everything in it)

What exactly it's wrong? And I am using my right credentials, pretty much everything used to work just fine, but after I've done a back-up restore and had to upload to a new directory, maybe it has some missing paths? I cannot put the code here as it has over 4000 lines. Here's a link for anyone wondering how it looks like. I've never changed anything, it probably came in with the hosting.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=96016331707954782437

Comment: It might help if you read the troubleshooting guide that the error links you to. the PHPMailer readme file tells you which files you need - for SMTP, you'll also need the `class.smtp.php` file. Please don't posts to external resource like that, especially ones that look like malware hosts.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying it for me.